# ARM linux process memory layout

Tags: arm, paging, virtual-memory

I am new to the ARM architecture. I want to know if the process memory layout of ARM Linux(Commonly used version) is any different from the x86 Linux. Does the rules of .text, .bss, .data, .stack, .heap are any different in ARM. Does it support virtual memory and paging, if yes from where the swap space is used as flash memory is read-only i guess. ARM Linux kernel has MMU enabled. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Might be a help: http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/developer/memory.txt

Comment: Helpfull.but couldnt find from where swap space is used as flash memory is readonly

Comment: For real Linux (not counting ucLinux for the Cortex-M3), build a kernel with swap support enabled and it'll use a swap partition if you give it one; build one without, and it won't. CONFIG_SWAP is enabled by default and a quick grep suggests only a minority of the arch/arm configs turn it off. Obviously swapping to a flash-based filesystem (eMMC, SD card, etc.) would be a great way to wear it out quickly (I'm not sure why you'd think they're all read-only) so it would only really make sense to provide a swap partition on a system with a real disk, but then that's true of any architecture.

Comment: What if the flash memory is limited like in server management evaluation board the flash memory is 32 MB and the ram size is 256 MB in this case is the flash memory sufficient for swap space. MMU is enabled for the kernel.

Comment: Voting to close a unclear or too broad.